# Дублирование элементов массива

Tags: javascript, массивы

Создать функцию, которая принимает массив, а возвращает новый, с дублированными элементами, входного массива. У меня такой код, но в нём ошибка, как правильнее

```js
function map(Array) {
    let napp = [];
        for (let i = 0; i<Array.length; i++){

        }
            return napp;
}

let doubleArray = Array.concat([1, 2, 3]);
console.log(doubleArray);
```

?

Comment: боюсь даже спрашивать, в чем ошибка в вашем коде с вашей точки зрения. какой порядок элементов вам нужен в результирующем массиве?  `1,2,3` => `1,1,2,2,3,3` или `1,2,3,1,2,3` или `1,2,3,3,2,1` или еще что?

Comment: Надо чтобы можно было добавить любое число, но в примере показано как: 1,2,3,1,2,3

Answer (score 3):

```js
function dblArr(a){
   return a.concat(a);
}

var a = [1,2,3];
console.log( dblArr(a) );
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function map(arr) {
    let napp = [];
        for (let i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
            napp.push(arr[i]);
        }
            return napp;
}
var arr = map([1,2,3]);

let doubleArray = arr.concat(arr);
console.log(doubleArray);
```

Comment: можете сказать, как тут вообще используется функция `map`, код которой вы дописали?

Comment: не правильно понял вопрос, извините. Исправил :)